# ViewPager2: setOnTouchListener() doesn't call

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I'm migrating my ViewPager to the new ViewPager2. Unfortunately with this new class, the `setOnTouchListener` is never called.

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "motionEvent.getAction()=" + motionEvent.getAction());
                ...
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: i had this issue too and it don't know why, and i wanted to extend the viewpager2 to override the touch methods but i couldn't because the viewpager2 is final !

Answer (score 22):

Because ViewPager2 is a ViewGroup, the final target is the recyclerview in it. The `setOnTouchListener` not called is because recyclerview intercepts the event and calls the `onTouchEvent` first.

The right way to add customised onTouch logic is to call
`mViewPager.getChildAt(0).setOnTouchListener{...}`